# Modifying ld.so paths before loading perl modules

Tags: linux, perl, module, shared-libraries

I'm trying to set a specific `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to load a modified version of libpcap instead of the system-wide one.

This works of course if I run the whole script with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/blah ./script_name`. I want to make this transparent for the user, so I tried setting `$ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'}`. This doesn't however change the behaviour. I tried to put it in the `BEGIN` block to make it work before other `use`-s, but no luck there either.

I suspect it's because of ld loading all the configs / configuring itself at the beginning of the process before any part of the script is run. Is there some way to make it work?

I'd like to avoid silly things like:

```
if (check_parent()) { $ENV...=.... ; `$0` ; exit }
```

(or external wrappers as have been suggested - the less cruft and random wrappers, the better)

Comment: How about using a wrapper bash script that will export any variables and then exec your perl script?

Comment: @thkala: That will work of course, but I've already got another wrapper for this script (and it's really not its responsibility to set env variables) and it would get hard to manage all the layers at some point. I'm looking for a way to do this without any outside helpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* replace the top of your script with

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/blah:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec perl -x -S "$0" "$@" || exit 1
#!perl

# rest of your script
```

Comment: Fearless and inventive. My kind of scum. +100000. - Jabba

Answer (score 0):

The reason setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside the Perl script has no effect is that by the time Perl is running, the dynamic loader has already read LD_LIBRARY_PATH and does not reread it.  Thus, even a BEGIN block is too late - the dynamic loader has already read what it needs.